# Running MQTT broker on a subdomain on my home server

Tags: subdomain, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a home server on my Raspberry Pi with a registered domain (say: `mysite.com`). I would like to use a subdomain to point to my `MQTT` broker running on the Pi so that I can use `mqtt.mysite.com` from outside my house.

In order to do that I have added a CNAME record to my DNS and verified that I can ping it.

However, I am not able to use the domain with MQTT. I am using `mosquitto`, the daemon is running on the Pi on the default port 1883. The port is open on the firewall via `ufw allow 1883`.

If I use the private IP address everything works fine:

```
mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.1.80 -p 1883 -t home/bedroom/temp -m 23.4
```

However if I use the subdomain

```
mosquitto_pub -h mqtt.mysite.com -p 1883 -t home/bedroom/temp -m 23.4
```

I get a `Connection refused` error.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you opened the right ports on your router and does it support hairpin routing?

Comment: I am not sure what that means actually. Based on a quick search I think I get the gist.  On my router I have forwarded the port 1883 to the private address (and port) of the MQTT daemon and that did the trick. Is that what you meant?

Comment: That's the first half. Not all home routers support (hairpin routing) accessing exposed services from the inside.

Comment: I have a Netgear Nighthawk R8000P and according to [this](https://kb.netgear.com/000049578/NETGEAR-Router-support-for-NAT-Loopback) hairpin routing is supported. My understanding is that it is equivalent to NAT loopback. Should I change something?

Comment: I just verified that without opening the port I cannot access it from outside. With the hindsight, this part, was actually obvious.

Comment: This is also really probably better asked on SuperUser and is off topic for Stack Overflow.